# How to set the page properties values under a node in the currentpage

Tags: extjs, aem

I need to set the cq:tags which is configured in page properties of the page to a node (jcr:content/samplenode). I overlay the page component but I didn't find the code to customize.  How to set the page properties values under a node in the currentpage ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the value of the default tag field in the page properties at `jcr:content/samplenode/cq:tags` instead of `jcr:content/cq:tags`, then change the value for the property "**name**" in the tags widgets from `./cq:tags` to `./samplenode/cq:tags`

For the default page component, the tag widget can be found at the location `/libs/foundation/components/page/tab_basic/items/basic/items/tags`.

**EDIT:**

Though i wouldn't suggest the following approach, inorder to achieve your required functionality, along with the above mentioned changes, add a beforesubmit event listener to the dialog with the value set to the following function.

```
function(comp){
    var response = CQ.HTTP.get(CQ.WCM.getPagePath() + '/_jcr_content/samplenode.json');
    if(!CQ.HTTP.isOk(response)) {
        comp.getField('./samplenode/cq:tags').name = 'cq:tags';
    }
}
```

The dialog listener is to be added as shown in the picture below.
[image]

Comment: Thank you Rakes... you r a Greek bro!!! . it is saving to samplenode. yes I know default tag widget location and overlaying this to my custompage component but I didn't find any jsp/js code to customize. I need to check if the node is available then only I need to add this property to sample node.

Comment: There is no jsp / code to customize this as this is using features of the SlingPostServlet to create the nodes and add the values. So are you saying that, even though i enter the tags, it should get saved only when the samplenode is present, else i should be ignoring it. Did i get it right?

Comment: yes, it should save after checking the node is present or not

Comment: It is working only if we open the page and configuring tags but when I am trying to configuring in siteadmin(right click on the page and click on properties), the tags are not getting stored. Even the configured tags are not loading.